# Save/Open Dynamically Created Controls In a Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to develop a program in which it could create forms and add controls to it at runtime.

It also should be able to save, (Open and Edit) the forms created with the new controls added it at Runtime.The Application starts In the Main form.

[image: Main Form Image LINK]

*CODE BEHIND **MAIN** Form*

```
private void Btn_CREATE_FORM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form_Properties fp = new Form_Properties();

        fp.Show();
    }

    private void BTn_ADD_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /// WHAT CODE SHOULD I ENTER TO ADD BUTON TO NEW FORM 
    }
```

Basically the main form is used to create/open/save new forms and add controls to it.

When the user clicks on **Create New Form** button the user will be presented with the following form **(FORM_PROPERTIES)** in which the user can customize the name, width and height of the new form.

[image: Form Properties Image LINK]

*CODE BEHIND **FORM_PROPERTIES** Form*

```
public partial class Form_Properties : Form
{
    public Form_Properties()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    String form_name;
    int form_width;
    int form_height;

    private void Btn_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        form_name = TBox_NAME.Text;
        form_width = Convert.ToInt32(TBox_WIDTH.Text);
        form_height = Convert.ToInt32(TBox_HEIGHT.Text);

        New_Form nf = new New_Form();

        nf.Text = form_name;
        nf.Width = form_width;
        nf.Height = form_height;

        nf.Show();
    }
}
```

The following image shows what happens at runtime based on the code I have written so far.

[image: Runtime Image LINK]

***ISSUES***

***Need help to Write Code***

1. To add controls to new form created.
2. To Save/Open/Edit Functionalities.

I also need to know the method to access properties of added controls at runtime.

**eg: If the user adds a text box to the NEW FORM and decides to type some text in it, I need a method to save that text.**

Is there a way for me to name the added controls?

Comment: For some good examples you can take a look at:

 - [Hosting Windows Forms Designers](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4351/hosting-windows-forms-designers/) by Tim Dawson
 - [Tailor Your Application by Building a Custom Forms Designer with .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20140419204547/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163871.aspx) by Sayed Y. Hashimi

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to build some kind of WinForms' form designer. Your program would be similar to [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) (though Glade is much more powerful).

I'm afraid the question is too broad, though. There are many questions to answer, for example, how do you describe the created interface.

While Glade uses XML, you can choose another format, such as JSON. Let's say that you have a **TextBox** with the word "example" inside it.

```
{ type:"textbox" text:"example" }
```

It seems you want to add your components to the form as in a stack. Maybe you could add its position. For example, a form containing a label 
("data"), a textbox ("example"), and a button ("ok"), would be:

```
{
    { pos:0, type:"label", text:"data" },
    { pos:1, type:"textbox", text:"example" },
    { pos:2, type:"button", text:"ok" },
}
```

But this is just a representation. You need to a) store this when the form is saved, and b) load it back when the form is loaded.

For that, you will need a class representing the components, such as:

```
public class Component {
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format( "position:{0}, text:{1}", this.Position, this.Text );
    }

    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class TextBoxComponent: Component {
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return base.ToString() + "type:\"textbox\"";
    }
}
```

...and so on. This is a big task, I'm afraid, with no simple answer.